# How to execute GUI Java application?

Tags: java

I have made some GUI Java application and exported it as "Executable Jar". But Windows shows me this file as RAR archieve, and I can't execute it! How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command line, run: `java -jar <jarfile>`.

From Windows Explorer, right-click on the JAR file, choose "**Open with...**" and select your local Java installation.

*Make sure you have a [JRE installed](http://www.java.com). Normally Windows will recognise JAR files and do the right thing with them. The fact that they are being identified (understandably) as an archive would hint that you have no JRE.*

Comment: I don't know which Java file I should choose

Comment: @ДенисНагибин the jar file itself

Comment: @ДенисНагибин on my machine, i would "open with" the following binary: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe`. hopefully yours is in a similar location and you can choose appropriately.